# Model not showing in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I have seen a lot of posts about this and tried most of what those answers say and no luck.

I have an app named photos with a models.py that looks like this

```
from django.db import models

class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
```

The app is installed:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'photos',
)
```

Admin.py like this:

```
from photos.models import Photo
from django.contrib import admin

class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Photo, PhotoAdmin)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'garthreckers.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I've run touch on settings.py and wsgi.py. I've runserver, syncdb, migrate.

And if it helps, here is a breakdown of my directory structure:

```
garthreckers
|-garthreckers
  |-__init__.py
  |-__init__.pyc
  |-settings.py
  |-settings.pyc
  |-urls.py
  |-wsgi.py
  |-wsgi.pyc
|-photos
  |-migrations
  |-__init__.py
  |-__init__.pyc
  |-admin.py
  |-admin.pyc
  |-models.py
  |-models.pyc
  |-tests.py
  |-views.py
|-manage.py
```

EDIT: vhost conf file

```
WSGIPythonPath /home/ubuntu/xxxxxxx.com/garthreckers

<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName www.xxxxxxx.com
ServerAlias xxxxxxx.com

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/xxxxxxx.com/garthreckers/garthreckers/wsgi.py

<Directory /home/ubuntu/xxxxxxx.com/garthreckers/garthreckers>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
    </Files> 
</Directory> 
<Directory /home/ubuntu/xxxxxxx.com/garthreckers/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory> 
<Directory /home/ubuntu/xxxxxxx.com/garthreckers/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What http server do you use and how do you serve your django app for that server (using wsgi, gunicorn, uwsgi)?

Comment: Apache & mod_wsgi. I included the conf file above

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it appear when do you do python manage.py runserver.  (I'd also suggest removing all the pyc's)

Comment: runserver doesn't fix it. I removed the pyc's and did runserver again just in case and nothing.

Comment: does it work locally? Did you try ./manage.py check (or ./manage.py validate)? Did you reset apache? The file is called `admin.py`right (not `Admin.py`)? Did you run `git pull` :) Also, nothing to do with your issue but in your code: `return self.name` => `return unicode(self.name)`

Comment: Actually don't have a local install yet. New to Python/Django and decided to just take advantage of AWS free 12 months. So didn't set up Git since not production or important site. Just for fun :) I've reloaded Apache but no restart. Will try that later when home. Tried both check and validate and nothing. It is admin.py.

Comment: Shamefully enough, it was simple. apache restart (instead of reload which I usually use) fixed it. Hate when its THAT simple. Want to make that an answer so I can give you credit François?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. I setup a fresh virtualenv, a fresh Django installation, copied your code verbatim and the Admin is all there as expected. I can't guess what is specifically wrong but, hey! good news your code is fine. Starting fresh is fast so perhaps it's worth a try. Remove all .pyc files and don't worry about Apache just yet. Once you know the project setup is working, then you can worry about the next step of Apache hosting. Here are the commands I ran:

```
django-admin startproject garthreckers
django-admin startapp photos
# copied your code into appropriate files
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
./manage.py createsuperuser
./manage.py runserver
```

Side tip: as of Django 1.7 you don't need `admin.autodiscover()`([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.autodiscover)).

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user logged in to the admin panel has rights to manage such a model.